# Check if data in a custom class has changed using C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I was curious what is the best way (preferrably faster one, from CPU standpoint) to see if data in my customer C# class has changed?

The class consists of various basic types: `int`, `long`, `string`, etc. and `List< string >` and `List < uint >` types.

My idea was to convert this class data into byte[] array and do SHA1 on the result, but converting every member into a byte array seems to be quite a long undertaking so I'm wondering if there's a faster way. I also thought to serialize it, but wouldn't it be an overkill for my purpose. (The resulting serialized byte array on my empty class is about 6000+ bytes!)

Anyway, what's your take on it?

Comment: add a 'modified' column?

Comment: No, that's not the case. One copy of this class' data is stored outside of my web app and when I receive it I need to see if it changed and if not, I won't process it again.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface in your Class.

That way all registered methods will be triggered if something changes.

See [How to implement it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't indicate it in the OP. I get this data from outside my application and I need to see if it's different from what I have.